# Redux: Add value in first reducer and then pass the newly created value to second reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Example redux tree with contact *Adam* in the *Friends* group:

```js
{
    groups: {
        1: {
            name: "Friends"
            contacts: [1]
        }
    }
    contacts: {
        1: {
            name: "Adam"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to create a new contact in the *Friends* group and the result would be something like:

```js
{
    groups: {
        1: {
            name: "Friends"
            contacts: [1, 2]
        }
    }
    contacts: {
        1: {
            name: "Adam"
        },
        2: {
            name: "Bethany"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I am creating the new contact id before I run the redux action on both reducers. However this feels really messy, is there a better way to go about doing this? My current code is below:

**contact.js**

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

function Contact({ createContact, groupId, newContactId }) {
    function onContactCreate(name) {
        createContact(newContactId, groupId, name);
    }
    // ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        newContactId: state.get('contacts').size + 1
    };
};

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        createContact: (newContactId, groupId, name) => dispatch({
            type: 'CREATE_CONTACT',
            newContactId,
            groupId,
            name
        })
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Contact);
```

**contact-reducer.js**

```js
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({});

function contactReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_CONTACT': {
            return state
                .set(action.id, fromJS({
                    name: action.name
                }));
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default contactReducer;
```

**group-reducer.js**

```js
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({});

function groupReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_CONTACT': {
            let id = action.groupId;
            return state
                .updateIn([id, 'contacts'], (contacts) => contacts.push(action.id));
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default groupReducer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do indeed have to create the ID before you dispatch the action. The ID shouldn't depend on the current state. If you use time travel or Redux Dev tools to edit history, the same action could create an item with a different ID. This would lead subsequent actions to use the incorrect ID.

In general, the identity of an object should be bound to the object and not created separately.

Comment: Yes what you're doing seems to me to be just great.

Comment: Are you able to explain this a bit further "In general, the identity of an object should be bound to the object and not created separately."? I don't really understand what it means.

Comment: Well, by letting the ID drowns on state, the ID would be added after the data. In particular, it could desynchronize like I outlined.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Last question, is my method to create the new contacts id ok? It seems a bit odd to me to create the id on the contact creator initialisation instead of when the "onContactCreate" function is run.

Comment: Well, the best place for it is an action creator. I see you don't use action creators. They are recommended, in particular for a case like this.

Comment: I think I do use action creators (like this? https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/actions.js) I just removed them to try and make my question more simple. I couldn't figure out how to access the redux state in my action, have you got an example I can look at?

Comment: You don't need to access state to create an ID. However, you can access state if you use [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk).

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at redux-thunk. Obviously I am missing something, but how would you create an ID if you don't know the existing IDs?

Comment: You can just generate a unique ID. `const getId=(()=>{ let next=0; return ()=>next++; })();`

Comment: Huh, took me awhile to understand but that is really clever. Anyways thanks for your help! I really appreciate you helping me get on the right track.